# record video programmatically on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, custom-controls, video-capture

Is there public interface in SDK 3.* to start video recording programmatically? Also how can I customize camera button appearance?

Thanks,

Nava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that right now. There has been some rumours that it might be possible in 3.2 though, but no idea how accurate that is.

Answer (score -2):

This is very late reply!

I have written a script that you can run to record your iphone screen.

Select your iPhone or iPad manually from the list of devices in QuickTime Player and run the script you’ll see your device’s screen replicated in the QuickTime window and gets recorded.

**Create a shell script and the following:**

```
osascript <<EOD
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    start (new movie recording)
    delay 5
    tell application "System Events"
          key down {command}
          keystroke "w"
          key up {command}
          key down {command}
          keystroke "s"
          key up {command}
    end  tell
end tell
EOD
```